# Galois group of tower of $p^{th}$ cyclotomiic extensions.

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

See exercise 7-1 in Milne's note (Page 98): https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FTc.pdf

[image]

I think there is a typo in it, and every group should be replaced by its multiplicative group of invertible elements. Especially, $Gal(\Omega/\Bbb Q) \equiv \Bbb Z_p^{\times}$.

Because we know that $Gal(\Bbb Q (\zeta_{p^m})/\Bbb Q) \equiv (\dfrac{\Bbb Z}{p^m\Bbb Z})^{\times}$.

Am I mistaken?

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks a lot.

Comment: And for $p$ odd, $\Bbb{Z}_p\cong Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)) $, the isomorphism is $$a \to (\zeta_{p^k} \to \zeta_{p^k}^{\textstyle (1+p)^{a\bmod p^{k-1}}})$$